# Adding a background to a sample of letters of a text object in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, text, background

Does anyone know how to highlight a sample of letters in a text object with a solid colour using [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/)? I saw a similar post with the question of how to highlight the entire text object (the post can be found [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/120294/inkscape-for-cartography-fill-the-background-of-a-text)), but I only want to highlight a sample of letters instead of the entire thing. I don't want to add a rectangle behind the text using the rectangle tool.

Here's an image to illustrate what I mean:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by rectangle, do you want the, and what do you mean by segment? This question is not very clear. By rectangle do you mean the shape, or do you mean the stroke that creates a border around the object? Typically segment is used to refer to path-segments, did you want to color background of the letters? Or do you want the letters to sit ontop of the background?

Comment: It sounds like you want to do somthing like in ***[this image I uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0Oje.png)*** ya?

Comment: Thank you for telling my to be more clear.

Comment: I'm not really an Inkscape user. In InDesign I would use a thick underline like in [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/124701). But Inkscape doesn't seem to have an easy way to underline part of a text. Looking at [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/67012) makes me think it's too quirky to work with. Just drawing a rectangle seems more appealing. Why is it that you don't want to do that?

Comment: I am an Inksape user. Text has no background attribute - there's no such thing - only a fill/stroke, so what you want is not possible.  Use a rectangle instead.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible, if you mean to do a common thing in text editors – setting a *background color* of (individual) letters.

Letters in Inkscape are created from paths, they have *no bounding box* (“a background”) as in text editors, so there is nothing as a *foreground / background color* – only a **stroke / fill color**.

From this follows that you may highlight a part of your text only by selecting it and then changing its *fill or stroke color*:

[image]

Comment: The reason I thought it was possible was because there was a way to do it to an entire text object as seen [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/120301/174261).

Comment: @JohnnyR., I understand you, but what you want is not possible in Inkscape, I'm sorry. Effects work on the whole objects only, not on a cutoff of a text object. You may break a text object into individual objects and apply an effect only on one of them, but then you lose all benefits of your original text object.