# Converting Underlined Text into a Path in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, text, path

So I created some underlined text in [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) by following [this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/67012) as a guide. Now I want to convert my text object into a path. Whenever I select my text and hit the `Object to Path` button under the `Path` menu, my text object becomes a path, but my underline disappears! **How do I preserve the underline when converting a text object into a path?**

---

*(HE LP )*

Comment: Text decoration is ignored when converting text to paths,. It's a known bug. [See here](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues/4822). The workaround would to be to draw lines manually.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I preserve the underline when converting a text object into a path?

Preserving the underline ***is not possible** in the current release version of Inkscape (1.2).* You may only (manually) create and add an appropriate underlining path.

Inkscape is still in progress to reach a full compliance with the SVG standard, so there are still SVG elements / attributes which are *not supported*, or are supported *only partially*.

The `text-decoration` is an example of such a partially supported attribute – Inkscape don't ignore it and displays it, but it presently *not considers it as a part of a text object*.

It follows besides other things from the impossibility to apply underline style directly from the Tool Control Bar of the Text tool. You may only manually (although comfortable from the *Inkscape XML Editor* or *Selectors and CSS* dialogs) add this attribute into the resulting SVG (XML) file.

Comment: Do you know of any third-party plugin that allows you to preserve the underline?

Comment: @Pirate GIG, AFAIK there is not such an extension.